# Property 'render' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Error:

Answer (score 5):

`ReactDOM` should be imported from `react-dom`, not `react`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: stupid me, thank you